Create a range of cells without overwrite
The below code creates a range of cells. Afterwards I use the range to import a formula.
If I add many cells the range starts to overwrite previous cells.
If .Cells(a, i).Value > 0 Then
    If rngDebit Is Nothing Then
        Set rngDebit = .Cells(a, i)
    Else
        Set rngDebit = Union(.Cells(a, i), rngDebit)
    End If
Else
    If rngCredit Is Nothing Then
        Set rngCredit = .Cells(a, i)
    Else
        Set rngCredit = Union(.Cells(a, i), rngCredit)
    End If
End If
Else
End If

Next a

'Import totals
If Not rngDebit Is Nothing Then
    .Cells(LastRow + 2, i).Formula = "=Sum(" & rngDebit.Address & ")"
Else
    .Cells(LastRow + 2, i).Value = 0
End If


the range.address property has a maximal length of 255 characters (the range itself can hold much more cells). Maybe that's your problem?

That's what i was thinking. Is there any possible solution?

Have a look to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78784729/7599798 and use the small function myAddress that's described there. Or write a UDF that calculates the Debit values.

If it's just a matter of calculating the sum, why not sum the cells up on the fly, without creating a union?

Get the summary of debit values with SUMIF formula, eg. =SUMIF(A:A,">0",A:A)

I would use SumIf(..) as @taller suggests, which would probably perform much faster than looping in vba:
.Cells(lastRow + 2, i).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & .Columns(i).Address & ", ""<0"")"

But if you prefer to DIY or want to add more complex functionality, then you could define a udf:
Public Function sumDebits(rRangeToSum) As Double
    Dim cV As Range
    For Each cV In rRangeToSum
        If cV < 0 Then sumDebits = sumDebits + cV
    Next cV
End Function

and then call the udf in a similar way:
.Cells(LastRow + 2, i).Formula = "=SumDebits(" & .columns(i).Address & ")"

